# LEX App Component Recommendations not displaying

Tags: lightning-apps, community-builder, community-cloud

Under Feature Settings >> Communities >> All Communities I have created a community named Creative Creators.

I open the workspace for Creative Creators and select Recommendations Tab.

I create an audience based upon New Members and put .1 Days as the length of time to include.

I then create a recommendation under custom channel one and select the Audience I created.

Next I go to my Lightning App Page and add the Recommendations module. The module displays empty.

My questions are:

1. Do I need to "join" Audience I created somewhere?
2. Is this the wrong place / type of recommendation for internal users of my Lightning App thus they aren't seeing it.
3. Is the .1 an invalid length of time thus it is failing and I just need to make it 1 and see what shows tomorrow?